# How to merge main to origin/main?

Tags: git, github

I had issues in my build and I did git reset hard to one of the older branches and now I am on that old branch but my origin/main is still on the new one.
How can I merge my changes from main to origin/main ?

For example - origin/main is on commit b7e4f25
I did git reset --hard 9ad219d (This was the earlier commit before b7e4f25).

No local branch main is on 9ad219d and origin/main and origin/HEAD is on b7e4f25.
I want to bring back origin/main and origin/HEAD to 9as219d.

Comment: You might not be asking how to do what you actually want to do. If you intended to do a hard reset, you can't `merge` that into `origin/main`, you would have to force push your changes. But I wouldn't do that unless you're sure that's what you want to do.

Comment: `origin/main` _is_ a branch. How can it be "on the new one"? Please revise to be more clear.

Comment: I did the edit.

Comment: OK. In that case you must force push. You can't merge.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to do it please ?

Comment: @JainamShah you didn't know it because you were thinking about "merge", but this is a duplicate of another question which answers your question.

Comment: That worked that you so much